# Slang expressions

Tags: grammar, words, slang

I want to know what this commentator's expressions means:

CONTEXT: a soccer commentator before a match.

> ヘイ！きょうもげんきにドリッブッてるかい！ぜんごくちゅうがくせいサッカーたいかいはまもなくキックオフだ！
>
> Hey! Are you ready to dribble in this shining day? This Young Soccer League match is about to start!

However, problems start here:

> オット　じっきょうは　ナゾのしゅっちょうアナ　おがいが　おくっちゃうヨーダ！
> ...　チカレタ。

(Otto or オット as for "watch out"? there's no any Otto mentioned before)'s condition due to trip's mystery (...) this アナ (announcer) is...

おがい doesn't appear in any dictionary (is some abbreviation of おねがい?)

おくっちゃう (ちゃう as for accident?), ヨーダ, and チカレタ also doesn't make any appereance. I searched for ちかる but seems that is not a verb. ヨーダ is not an inversed だよ?

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Concerning ヨーダ, it will be easier to understand to parse as 「送っちゃうよー」だ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- オット -- "oops!"; probably indicating that he almost forgot say the following line
- おがい -- apparently the name of the commentator himself; in apposition with "ナゾのしゅっちょうアナ"
- おくっちゃう -- "送る(to deliver)" + "ちゃう"; I figure the "ちゃう" is randomly thrown in just for the heck of it (which is in character with his facetious way of speaking) since its canonical uses of expressing "end up doing...", "regret", etc. do not seem to fit in a reasonable way
- ヨーダ -- probably not the inversion of だよ, because 送っちゃうだよ is ungrammatical (though I wouldn't put it past this clownishly-talking annoucner that he's doing it on purpose for comical effect); also probably not an alternative spelling of the "ようだ" meaning "look like"; most likely (what I'll call, for lack of better term in my knowledge,) the compound sentence-ending particle "よーだ", which usually adds a nuance of jocular mockery or triumph to a statement (somewhat like "so there!", "ha!", "how do you like that!", I think); and definitely not Yoda from Star Wars
- チカレタ -- a childish-humorous way of saying "疲れた (tired)".

My brave attempt at translation:

> Oopsie, I almost forgot! The live commentary will be delivered by yours truly, the mysterious out-of-town announcer Ogai! Haaaaah! ...I'm tired.